# Unresolved overloaded function type while calling template member function in a class template

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
struct Test {
    template <int S>
    bool call();
};

template <>
bool Test::call<0>() {
    return false;
}

template <>
bool Test::call<1>() {
    return true;
}

template <int S, typename T>
static void func(T& t) {
    t.call<S>();
}

int main()
{
    Test t;
    func<0>(t);
}
```

I got a compilation error:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘void func(T&)’:
a.cpp:19:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
a.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void func(T&) [with int S = 0; T = Test]’:
a.cpp:25:14:   required from here
a.cpp:19:5: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
```

If I put `t.call<0>()` or `t.call<1>()` in the `main()` function, it works fine.  Can someone tell me why template argument deduction doesn't work for this code?  I am not sure why passing in a type with a partially-specialized template member function won't work in this case.

Comment: No offense, but I don't understand why this question has two upvotes. Its a clear case of the use of `template` keyword.

Answer (score 5):

You need to say

```
template <int S, typename T>
static void func(T& t) {
    t.template call<S>();
}
```

Because `T` is a dependent type name, the compiler doesn't know that `call()` is a template function, so you have to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disambiguate the parse using `template` keyword:

```
template <int S, typename T>
static void func(T& t)
{
    t.template call<S>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you wanted to write

```
t. template call<S>();
```

The name `call` is clearly dependent and, thus, not considered to be template unless it is explicitly stated that it is a template. Currently, I can't easily check if this is this is the only issue.